# Partitions of n into k distinct parts which are multiples of given numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, partitions, enumerative-combinatorics

Is there anything known about the number of partitions of an integer $n$ into $k$ distinct parts in the following way?

Let $a_1,\dotsc,a_k\geqslant1$ be given integers. In how many ways can we write $n$ as $$n=a_1m_1+\dotsb+a_km_k$$
$m_i$, $i=1,\dotsc,k$, being positive integers such that $a_im_i\neq a_jm_j$ for $i\neq j$? Does such partitions have a name in the literature?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90381/

Comment: Do you want $m_i>0$?

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich Yes

Comment: for what it worth, this number of partitions is the coefficient of  $t^kx^n$ i the product $\prod_{m=1}^\infty (1+\tau(m)tx^m)$ (here $\tau(n)$ counts the positive integer divisors of $n$, and the partitions obtained by permutations of $a_im_i$'s are identified)